# Как избавиться от превышения длины строки POST запроса

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Использую base64 для отправления изображений на сервер, и иногда сталкиваюсь с проблемой превышения максимальной длины строки. Как это можно обойти?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код POST:

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
        { "kod", "111" },
        { "id_user", user.Id },
        { "image", encodedFile },
        { "title", "654321" },
        { "text", "1234526" }
       };

        var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("ссылка", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: А причем тут POST. Если у вас данные в URI, то это видимо GET ... А POST для того и придуман, что бы данные были не в URI а в теле запроса

Comment: @Mike обновил вопрос